# How to remove previous level entities in AndEngine?

Tags: java, android, xml, andengine

in my game,I've 6 levels that any level has a XML file...I've a problem with end level...when player collide to sprite(it is in end level) I want to load next level but in under code when load next level,entities of two level is shown...How to remove previous level entities?

XML file

```
<level width="10000" height="1000" background="back1">  
<entity x="100" y="100" type="sp"/>
<entity x="230" y="100" type="fa"/>
<entity x="440" y="190" type="su"/>
<entity x="660" y="240" type="sp"/>
...
<entity x="415" y="340" type="coin1"/>
<entity x="465" y="340" type="coin1"/>
<entity x="805" y="360" type="coin2"/>
<entity x="60" y="140" type="player"/>
<entity x="6000" y="360" type="levelEnd"/>
</level>
```

GameScene

```
public void loadLevel(int levelID) {
levelLoader.registerEntityLoader(new EntityLoader<SimpleLevelEntityLoaderData>(
                    TAG_ENTITY) {
                public IEntity onLoadEntity( final String pEntityName,
                        final IEntity pParent,
                        final Attributes pAttributes,
                        final SimpleLevelEntityLoaderData  pSimpleLevelEntityLoaderData)
                        throws IOException {
                    final int x = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(
                            pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_X);
                    final int y = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(
                            pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_Y);
                    final String type = SAXUtils.getAttributeOrThrow(
                            pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE);

                    final Sprite levelObject;
                    if (type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_LEVEL_END)) {
                        levelObject = new Sprite(x, y,
                                resourceManager.game_end_region, vbom) {
                            @Override
                            protected void onManagedUpdate(
                                    float pSecondsElapsed) {
                                super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

                                if (player.collidesWith(this)) {

                                    swipeScene();
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        levelObject.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(
                                        new ScaleModifier(1, 1, 1.3f)));
                    }
}
```

swipeScene:

```
    public void swipeScene() {
    resourceManager.mMusic1.stop();
    createHUD();
    createPhysics();
    resourceManager.loadGameResources();
    loadLevel(SceneManager.getInstance().levelN + 1);
    setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
}
```

Comment: onCollide() just remove whole scene and create new one..!! Plus make sure to release all resources also..!!

Comment: I'm new with engine...may explain further or introduce resource?

Comment: `Resource` means any `sprite` or `TextureAtlas` you have created for last game level..!!

Comment: yes...but how to release them?

Comment: `this.service.getTextureManager().unloadTexture(texturename);`  or `texturename.unload()` ..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is regarding to release resources in AndEngine :

You can release resources by :

**Remove Textures :**

```
this.service.getTextureManager().unloadTexture(texturename); 
texturename.unload();
```

Reference : http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/flappychick/3/

**Remove entities :**

```
yourEntity.detachSelf();
yourEntity.dispose();
```

Reference : http://www.matim-dev.com/how-to-safely-remove-sprite.html